# Using twilio with standard a standard POST or GET

Tags: twilio

Perhaps I'm just missing it, but is there a way to send an SMS message with twilio using a simple GET or POST? I was hoping for something like (shorthand): twilio.com/sendsms?pn=5555555555~msg=Here's the message~other parameters blah blah blah.

Again, I'm not trying to be specific or accurate in the above anemic example. I'm just trying to convey what I was looking for. I'm not seeing that type of example on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure, just POST to the SMS resource of our REST API:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms

Hope that helps